# Angular routing redirectTo displays wrong component

Tags: angular, redirect, routes

I know there are already several answers to this question but none of them helped me. My issue is that the router redirect doesn't redirect to the correct page and I can't find out why. My setup is:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'start', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'start', component: StartComponent, canActivate: [UManagementGuard] },
  { path: 'history', loadChildren: () => import('./history/history.module').then(m => m.HistoryModule), canActivate: [UManagementGuard]
  },
  { path: 'preview', component: PreviewComponent, canActivate: [UManagementGuard] },
  { path: 'live', loadChildren: () => import('./live/live.module').then(m => m.LiveModule),
    canActivate: [UManagementGuard] },
  { path: 'p-help', component: PHelpComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/lotList',  pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

So when I run the app it works fine when I start with:
**http://localhost:4200/start**

But when I call **http://localhost:4200** or **http://localhost:4200/**
it displays the **PreviewComponent** but not the **StartComponent**???

I already tried:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/start', pathMatch: 'full' }
or
{ path: '', component: StartComponent }
```

Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: You might want to check what `UManagementGuard` is doing, probably another redirect happens there.

Comment: I disabled the Guard and still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the bug.

My PreviewComponent had been a lazy loaded module and I changed it. But I forgot to remove the PreviewRoutingModule which still fired in an redirected any empty Route to it's own start component.